# How get extract unique dictionary from list of dictionary with preference of value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary below

```
test = [ { 'id': '195', 'Name': 'i', 'Email': 'chdtn@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product' }, 
        { 'id': '219', 'Name': 'umar', 'Email': 'ddhi@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product' }, 
        { 'id': '74', 'Name': 'Are', 'Email': 'ddhit@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester' },
        { 'id': '24', 'Name': 'Mee', 'Email': 'huul@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester' },
        { 'id': '230', 'Name': 'abc', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester' },
        { 'id': '220', 'Name': 'Sc', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product' },
        { 'id': '230', 'Name': 'Sn', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester' } ]
```

- I need to extract unique email from above list dict
- I need to give give role preference `Product` then to `Tester`

My Code is below

```
dict([(d['Email'], d) for d in test]).values()
```

My Out:

```
dict_values([{'id': '195', 'Name': 'i', 'Email': 'chdtn@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product'}, 
{'id': '219', 'Name': 'umar', 'Email': 'ddhi@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product'}, 
{'id': '74', 'Name': 'Are', 'Email': 'ddhit@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'}, 
{'id': '24', 'Name': 'Mee', 'Email': 'huul@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'}, 
{'id': '230', 'Name': 'Sn', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'}])
```

Here in my out

```
{'id': '230', 'Name': 'Sn', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'}
```

has to replace with

```
{ 'id': '220', 'Name': 'Sc', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product' }
```

because "Product" have higher preference.

How to update my code? `dict([(d['Email'], d) for d in test]).values()`

Comment: Do the first two Dictionaries have different Keys from the rest? They have "Account" for th last key rather than "role" of the rest?

Comment: no there is only one input dict, I need to give give role preference Product then to Tester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is in case you would like to insist on using dictionaries.
We go from one row to another. Check if the email is already in the new dictionary as key.

- If not, we add this as a new one.
- If so, we check our new row. If our new role is "product", we will delete what was already in the dictionary, and add the new row.

```
new_dict = {}
for row in test:
    if row["Email"] not in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict.update({row["Email"]: row})
    else:
        if row["role"]=="Product":
            new_dict.pop(row["Email"])
            new_dict.update({row["Email"]: row})
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try it with two loops; once to get the unique emails, and second time to make sure to prioritize "Product".

It wasn't clear what happens if there is no "Product" for duplicate "Emails", so in the loop below, the first email is selected in that case.

```
tmp = {}
for d in test:
    tmp.setdefault(d['Email'], []).append(d)
    
out = []
for k, lst in tmp.items():
    if len(lst) == 1:
        out.append(lst[0])
    else:
        for d in lst:
            if d['role'] == 'Product':
                out.append(d)
                break
        else:
            out.append(lst[0])
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '195', 'Name': 'i', 'Email': 'chdtn@gmail.com', 'Account': 'Product'},
 {'id': '219', 'Name': 'umar', 'Email': 'ddhi@gmail.com', 'Account': 'Product'},
 {'id': '74', 'Name': 'Are', 'Email': 'ddhit@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'},
 {'id': '24', 'Name': 'Mee', 'Email': 'huul@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'},
 {'id': '220', 'Name': 'Sc', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it to a `data frame` and `drop_duplicates` by `Email` after sorting the column `role`.

```
test = [ { 'id': '195', 'Name': 'i', 'Email': 'chdtn@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product' }, 
        { 'id': '219', 'Name': 'umar', 'Email': 'ddhi@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product' }, 
        { 'id': '74', 'Name': 'Are', 'Email': 'ddhit@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester' },
        { 'id': '24', 'Name': 'Mee', 'Email': 'huul@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester' },
        { 'id': '230', 'Name': 'abc', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester' },
        { 'id': '220', 'Name': 'Sc', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product' },
        { 'id': '230', 'Name': 'Sn', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester' } ] 

df = pd.DataFrame(test)


df1 = df.sort_values(by = ["Email", "role"], ascending = True)
res_df = df1.drop_duplicates(["Email"])

output_list = []
for i in res_df.values :
    output_list.append(dict([("id", i[0]), ("Name", i[1]), ("Email", i[2]), ("role", i[3])]))

> output_list

[{'id': '195', 'Name': 'i', 'Email': 'chdtn@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product'},
 {'id': '219', 'Name': 'umar', 'Email': 'ddhi@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product'},
 {'id': '74', 'Name': 'Are', 'Email': 'ddhit@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'},
 {'id': '220', 'Name': 'Sc', 'Email': 'deyan@gmail.com', 'role': 'Product'},
 {'id': '24', 'Name': 'Mee', 'Email': 'huul@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'}]
```